# Guzzle - Access to code on server error

Tags: php, request, guzzle

I connecting to API by Guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();

try {
    $res = $client->post( 'xxx' . $this->url , [
        'headers'   => $headers, 
        'json'      => $data,
    ]);

} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo json_decode( $e->getResponse()->getBody(), true );
}
```

And it's working but when it's 'catch', I need to get code from response but I getting:

```
Server error: `POST XXXXX` resulted in a `555 Error` response: {"status":"ERROR","errors":[{"message":"Subscribers already exists in this subscribers list","code":1304}]}
```

And I can't get the code. How to do this?

**UPDATE**
Here is screen with full response.
[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the exception code? Or the HTTP return status code?

Comment: @AlexHowansky HTTP. This code -> ```"code":1304```

Comment: You're going to have to look at documentation for whatever software is running on the server

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the response from the exception. Guzzle throws a special [`BadResponseException`](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Exception/BadResponseException.php) in case of failure, so take a look at this class.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (BadResponseException $exception) {
    // 555
    $exception->getCode();

    $appError = json_decode(
        $exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(),
        true
    );
    // 1304
    $appErrorCode = $appError['errors'][0]['code'];
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to `->getContents()` in the end. And I hope you've got the idea — the exception contains the response, with which you can work as with a usual response (extract JSON and so on).